# Unable to build and run pom file, Its showing error. Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:21

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-2, eclipse-kepler

I tried my best to resolve this issue by myself but didn't get any solution. I don't know why this error coming while it was working fine earlier.

System: 32-bit Windows
Eclipse Kepler

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
```

This error showing in pom file in header

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:21 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
 reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:
 21 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000

Comment: The message implies there seemed to be a problem with your connection to maven central. Proxy ? Have you tested on command line? Furthermore just remove your local repository or only the particular folder `org/apache/maven/plugins/`.

Comment: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will 
 not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
 resources-plugin:jar:2.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000

Comment: Check you connection to maven central? Are you behind a proxy etc. ?